# How do I create custom taxonomy as a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to create a category "University" for the post type "Courses". However, I also want to not just keep university as a category but create a custom post type in order to display the detailed university information.

I have successfully created "university" post type and "courses" post type with categories.

```php
<?php

    function my_plugin() {

        // Courses Post type with University as a category
        register_post_type( 'Courses', array(
            'public' => true,
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
        ));

        // University Post type
        register_post_type( 'university', array(
            'public' => true,
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
        ));
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin' );

?>
```

Somehow, I cannot relate custom post type "university" with "Courses" such that it appears as a category of courses as well as a CPT itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible in WordPress. An object can only be a post type or a taxonomy, not both.

A solution would be to create both the post type and the taxonomy, and then create your own database table to save the relations between both. A more simple solution (but depending on the way you need to get the relations) would be to use Advanced Custom Fields, and use that to link them together.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I cannot figure out how to filter posts by relationship field values. The code get_field("relationship")[0]->post_title returns the related post title, but I cannot filter posts when I use it in 'meta_query' key.

Comment: Have a look at the ACF documentation for the relationship field. They offer a solution for both the basic loop as well as using WP_Query: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

Comment: I have been through the doc, I couldn't find anything that helps me filter posts by their related post's title or custom fields. Could you please show me a reference if you have one?

Comment: Why would you want to filter by title? You said you wanted to relate both post types. If you use ```get_field('relationship_field_name')``` inside a query of type A, you get all the posts from type B that you've selected as related. If you want to use it in a WP_Query, you can use the example where they use the ```post__in``` option.

Answer (score 0):

As Sjors says, you can make a connection/relation between two CTP.

The ADC plugin allows it.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/